# meteor create user for integration test

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-velocity

I have some server methods that requires logged in user. Simply:

```
'myServerMethod': function () {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  if(!user) {
    return null;
  }

  //do some action
}
```

Now, I want to test this method (`Server Integration Test`). How would I create user for my server test purpose? I am using Meteor with Velocity.

Answer (score 3):

I use this function (`server/integration/lib/helpers.js`) in those tests:

```js
global.stubLoggedInUser = function (user) {
  spyOn(Meteor, 'user').and.returnValue(user);
  spyOn(Meteor, 'userId').and.returnValue(user._id);
  spyOn(Meteor.users, 'findOne').and.returnValue(user);
};
```

Comment: Is there in anyway I can actually log in the user instead of mocking the method? This also sounds ok

Answer (score 1):

This is the method which tests if there are any users and if there are not it creates one:

```
if(Meteor.users.find().count() == 0) {
 var id = Accounts.createUser({
    email: "someemail",
    password: "somepassword",
    profile: { name: "someusername"}
  });
```

You could use it to test if there are users.

Comment: As I understand and tried http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser It only returns id of created user but does not log in.